# angular 4 date pipe shortTime format with update every minute

Tags: javascript, angular, date, time, pipe

I need a working Digital clock in angular 4 
 
tried to make it with normal javascript and setInterval to run function every 60 sec . but the string interpolation not update the time when the property changed.

```
theDate = new Date();
theDay = this.theDate.getDay();
hours = this.theDate.getHours();
minutes = this.theDate.getMinutes();
session = "AM";
ngOnInit() {
    if (this.hours == 0) {
        this.hours = 12;
    }

    if (this.hours > 12) {
        this.hours = this.hours - 12;
        this.session = "PM";
    }
    this.stringHours = (this.hours < 10) ? "0" + this.hours : this.hours;
    this.stringMinutes = (this.minutes < 10) ? "0" + this.minutes : this.minutes;
    this.clock = this.stringHours + ":" + this.stringMinutes + " " + this.session;
    this.refreshClock();
}
refreshClock() {
    setInterval(() => {
        this.hours = this.theDate.getHours();
        this.minutes = this.theDate.getMinutes();
        this.stringHours = (this.hours < 10) ? "0" + this.hours : this.hours;
        this.stringMinutes = (this.minutes < 10) ? "0" + this.minutes : this.minutes;
        this.clock = this.stringHours + ":" + this.stringMinutes + " " + this.session;
        console.log('work');
    }, 1000)

}
```

so I tried angular date pipe but it's also not updating time it's just refresh it after refreshing app.

TypeScript

```
theDate = new Date();
```

HTML

```
 {{ theDate | date :'shortTime' }}
```

angular date pipe: 
https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: show the serinterval code

Comment: Can you add the full code to the question and update it

Comment: It should work, see this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7hk1yd

Comment: In your `setInterval()` you are not updating `theDate ` at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed to update `theDate` inside `setInterval()`

```
refreshClock() {
    setInterval(() => {
        this.hours = this.theDate.getHours();
        this.minutes = this.theDate.getMinutes();
        this.stringHours = (this.hours < 10) ? "0" + this.hours : this.hours;
        this.stringMinutes = (this.minutes < 10) ? "0" + this.minutes : this.minutes;
        this.clock = this.stringHours + ":" + this.stringMinutes + " " + this.session;
        console.log('work');
        // add this line
        this.theDate = newly calculated date
    }, 1000)

}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7hk1yd)